# Lightroom 6 - Smart collection: search for pictures containing more than 'x' keywords/people

Tags: lightroom, keywords, smart-collections, lightroom-6, face-detection

I would like to search for pictures containing more than 'x' keywords. The goal is to search for pictures containg more than 'x' people to find out which pictures are groups of people. Is that possible?
In my case, it's possible tha if there are more than 3 people faces tagged I consider it a group picture.
Is such a search possible?

Thanks a lot!

Simon

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called [Any Filter](http://johnrellis.com/lightroom/anyfilter.htm) by John R. Ellis that allows you to do this kind of search. The plugin is something you would have to buy, but there is no set price; just pay what you think is fair for the added functionality.

Comment: Seems not working for what needed, btw I'm asking the author. In case of news I'll update this answer :)

Comment: If you are only tagging pictures with peoples names it will definitely work. You just need to make sure you have the syntax right.

Comment: heres how i did it on mine: http://imgur.com/YnAVmGj

Comment: I've tested it but seems not working... Let mi double check. Thanks!

Comment: I confirm that's not working. The author of the plugin has answerred me via mail: _"Unfortunately, Any Filter doesn't give you a way to count keywords (or other multi-valued criteria) that match some condition.  It lets you match the total number of keywords, but not the number of keywords that are, say, a subkeyword of People."_
So, technically, the people are tagged this way:
XMP-dc field: Keyword "Subject" contains: "person1*person2*person3*person4". AFAYK The "Subject" fiueld contains the keywords used by Lightroom, divided by "*".
So the plugin is not working :(